# GridView + Fragments + onClickListener = weird behavior

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments

I've noticed a problem with my gridview/fragments. I'm changing my fragments by clicking on a gridview item, but whenever my app is running in background for a few hours, clicking on a gridview item gets really weird/incorrect.

For example I've got 4 items in my gridview: 
A, B, C & D
Click on A to view fragment1.
Click on B to view fragment2 (and so on).

If I now click on A, it should switch to fragment1, but nothing happens.
Then, If I click on B, it should switch to fragment2, but it's switching to fragment1.
Click then on C and it will switch to fragment2, but not to fragment3, as it should.

The click-event is basically always 1 step behind.

If I restard the app, everything is working as it should.

This is my onItemClickListener:

```
    item_gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int positionBasic, long id) {

                    if(positionBasic == 0)
                    {
                        Fragment fragmentItem001 = new Fragment1();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                        transaction.replace(R.id.itemDescrFragment, fragmentItem001);

                        transaction.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(ItemDescrFragment.this, "" + positionBasic, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                    if(positionBasic == 1)
                    {
                        Fragment fragmentItem002 = new Fragment2();
                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

                        transaction.replace(R.id.itemDescrFragment, fragmentItem002);

                        transaction.commit();

                        Toast.makeText(ItemDescrFragment.this, "" + positionBasic, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
             }
```

The Toast is always showing the correct item-position, but it won't switch to the correct fragment. The rest of the code is pretty much the same as the [Android Developer example.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Comment: do you ever add a fragment?

Comment: Yes, I'm doing that in the onCreate-method.